# Getting error 400 bad request in retrofit but works on postman

Tags: android, api, post, retrofit2

I have to send images and data to Retrofit2 multipart. The image may contain multiple images or no images at all. If you set the image to `null` in the postman and put the jsonObject as it is, it will be sent. But in the android studio, it is not being sent. I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
interface myRetrofitInterface {
@Multipart
@POST("--my--")
fun Question(
    @Header("X-ACCESS-TOKEN") X_ACCESS_TOKEN: String,
    @Part ("Que") Que: RequestBody,
    @Part images: List<MultipartBody.Part?>?,
    ): Call<--myResponse-->
```

}

Service.kt

```
fun Question(
    jwt: String, userIdx: Long, CategoryIdx: Long, title: String, Url: String?, images: ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part?>?
) {

    val myService = getRetrofit().create(--myRetrofitInterface--::class.java)

    val jsonObject =
        JSONObject("{\"userIdx\":${userIdx},\"CategoryIdx\":${CategoryIdx},\"title\":\"${title}\",\"Url\":\"${Url}\"}").toString()
    val Que = jsonObject.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())
    Log.d("json/jsonObject", jsonObject)

    --myView--.onLoading()

    --myService--.Question(
        jwt, Que, images
    ).enqueue(object : Callback<-- myResponse --> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<--myResponse-->, response: Response<--myResponse-->) {
        Log.d("API-RESPONSE", response.toString())
        Log.d("API-error", response.errorBody()!!.string())
        //                Log.d("json/jsonObject", jsonObject)
        if (response.isSuccessful && response.code() == 200) {
            val resp = response.body()!!
            Log.d("API-SUCCESS", resp.toString())

            when (resp.code) {
                1000 -> --myView - . onSuccess (resp.result)

                else -> --myView--.onFailure(resp.code, resp.message)
            }
        }
    }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<--myResponse-->, t: Throwable) {
        -myView--.onFailure(400, "error.")
        Log.d("API-ERROR", t.message.toString())
    }
    })
}
```

Log

```
D/json/jsonObject: {"userIdx":13,"CategoryIdx":5,"title":"asd","Url":"jkjk"}
D/API-RESPONSE: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=, url=--my Url--}
D/API-error: {"timestamp":"2022-04-10T18:36:45.061+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"--my path--"}
```

Comment: We'd pretty much need the server code to determine this.  All a 400 tells us is that the app that received the request rejected it.  It could have done that for any app specific reason.

Comment: Is it a problem with the server?

Comment: Maybe.  Or maybe a problem with the data you're sending it.  But we can't tell-  all we know is the server rejected your request.  Whether its the server or the client that's wrong is indeterminable from this.